# Conditional DateDiff

Tags: php, datediff

I had visited some of the post retrieving the date difference between 2 dates in SO but it doesn't gave me the answer I was seeking. Same for reading the documentation, I had problem understanding how it works.

I have tried coding it but it doesn't behave like what I was expecting. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$currentDate = new DateTime();
$createDateJoin = date_create($getDate['date_joined']);
$dateJoin = date_format($createDateJoin, "Y-m-d");

$yearDifference = $currentDate->diff($createDateJoin);

  if ($yearDifference->d < 31 && $yearDifference->m = 0 && $yearDifference->y == 0) {
       echo $yearDifference->d . " days";
        } else if ($yearDifference->m > 3) {
              echo $yearDifference->m . " month";
        } else if ($yearDifference->y > 1) {
              echo $yearDifference->y . " years";
      } else {
              echo "Not yet assigned";
       }
 ?>
```

As you can see from my code above, I am trying to do a print when after calculating the difference between the 2 dates, it meets the condition of `$yearDifference->`.The behavior from the program that I have experienced does not print out the things I want accordingly (E.g Staff working more than 1 year will print out how many years they have work, months for those who just came in and new staff less than a month will print out days).

I would like to know how does `->d/m/y` works and how can I actually make use of the `d`,`m` and `y` to draw out the specific date correctly. And I also noticed that when I treat `$yearDifference` as a `String` or `int`, it comes out different result for the conditions. So what should I treat the type to be to manipulate it more easily? Greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get  the date different method diff() object returns more values to check you can print_r your object that will print all data member that are returned via diff() method

```
<?php
echo get_date_diff(strtotime('1990-10-12'),strtotime('2015-10-14'));
function get_date_diff($date,$dateEnd) {
    $dStart = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $date));
    $dEnd = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", $dateEnd));
    $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
   return($dDiff->y.' years <br>'.$dDiff->m.' months <br>'.$dDiff->d. ' days');
}

 ?>
```